# Can Paypal make money transfers to international bank accounts

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, currency, banking

We want to pay to our customers on their bank accounts internationally as per their services to us. My questions are:

1. Can `Paypal` do that?
2. Do they have APIs that provides such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal APIs that send money facilitate PayPal Account to PayPal Account payments but not direct to Bank.

Some Products that support PayPal to PayPal are these:
 - Payouts: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/
 - Implicit payments with Adaptive Payments: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/